# Connecting to locahost from android device using a hostname with dynamic IP addresses (Changing Constantly)

Tags: networking, mobile, tcp, ip, html

CONTEXT OF QUESTION:

I have a computer running a local webpage on a WAMP server. The computer is connected to a wireless connection.

I have an android tablet that is connected to the same wireless network.

PURPOSE (WHAT I WANT TO DO):

I want to be able to access the local webpage on the WAMP server using a hostname through my APP.

WHAT I HAVE ALREADY TRIED:

I can already address the webpage from my app by using the ip address of the computer (http://192.168.x.x/Webpage_Name). However, since my ip is dynamic (changing constantly) this implementation will not work. Please correct me if I am wrong.

My idea was to use edit the hostfile of the computer. However, my understanding is that a hostfile is static meaning that it can not resolve hostnames to changing ip addresses (it only stores an ip address and its corresponding host name). Furthermore the hostfile would not be on the Android device so the android device would not be able to connect to the server using the hostname specified in the hostfile. Please correct me if I am wrong.

My second idea was to use a DynamicDNS service. However, my only problem with that is if I want a free third party service to provide the DNS my webpage information would have to go through the internet. I want this webpage to remain local so I think DNS would not be an option. Please correct me if I am wrong.

My third idea was to first create a TCP connection between the Computer and Android device through the app. Then I would send the IP address of the computer in a string from the computer to the android device. Then the android device could use the ip address that was sent to connect to the local server. Now my understanding is that you need the ip address and port to create a TCP connection between the android device and the computer and this is why I think this implementation will not work. Since I need to hard code the ip address in this option aswell the problem persists.

MAIN QUESTION (WHAT I WANT TO KNOW FROM YOU GUYS):

Does anyone know of any other options to solve this problem? If I have wrongly understood one of the options (WHAT I HAVE ALREADY TRIED section) above and you think there is a way to make them work, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem. I create a multicast socket client-server system between the computer running the WAMP and the mobile device. The computer would behave as the server and the mobile device would behave as the client. Once the connection is established I get the ip address of the computer in the server-side code. Then I send the ip address as a string from the computer to the client (mobile device) through the multicast socket. Then the mobile device creates the proper URL to the specified webpage on the WAMP server using the ip address provided and loads that URL.

See this page http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html for example code for the server client system.